# Efficient Swap Using References?

Tags: c++

I've been reading up on move semantics, and I believe that a really efficient swap is the following (we'll keep everything as int for now instead of using generics, for ease):

```
void swap(int& a, int& b) { 
    int tmp = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b); 
    b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

That's the correct swap implementation (for ints) right? Line 2 doesn't create an extra item in RAM for `tmp`, right?

My other question is, does this same code using references instead of std::move also do just as well of a job (as in, not creating an extra variable for `tmp`) as the Move Semantics example above?

```
void swap(int& a, int& b) { 
    int tmp = &a;
    a = &b; 
    b = &tmp;
}
```

Does the above code create an extra variable for `tmp`? Does it correctly swap `a` and `b`?

Comment: There is no difference between moving and copying for POD types. A better test example would be to use a non-POD movable type, like `std::string`.  And yes, line 2 allocates memory for `tmp`, and in your second example, `tmp` is always a copy of `a` (and BTW, your use of `&` inside the function is wrong).

Comment: A reference is a pointer with extra restrictions added (can't be re-assigned, can't create an array of them).  Why not just pass pointers and use `<T>* tmp = a; *a = b; *b = tmp;` ?  If not just swapping pointers you do need to create a full extra object as tmp, to hold a

Comment: @Dave - "*A reference is a pointer*" - not from the standard's perspective, it is not. Though using a pointer is how many commonly used compilers *implement* references under the hood.

Comment: `int tmp = &a;` is an error  (pointer cannot be assigned to integer without a cast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built-in types do not have a move constructor or move assignment operator, so your first version is really no different from

```
void swap(int& a, int& b)
{ 
    int tmp = a;
    a = b; 
    b = tmp;
}
```

Your second version [won't compile](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%0A%0Avoid+swap(int%26+a,+int%26+b)+%7B+%0A++++int+tmp+%3D+%26a%3B%0A++++a+%3D+%26b%3B+%0A++++b+%3D+%26tmp%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+8.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g83,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4). Most likely, however, you just meant to write the same thing as my version above anyways. Both versions introduce a temporary variable named `tmp` to hold on to the value that needs to be assigned to one swappee while the other one has its value changed.

Do not operate under the assumption that every construct in your code, such as a variable, has exactly one corresponding construct in the generated machine code, such as an "extra item in RAM", that it will always result in. This is not how modern compilers work. The job of a compiler is not to take every line of source code and perform a 1:1 replacement with a specific sequence of machine instructions. The job of a compiler is to take the entire program that you have described in the C++ language and generate an [*equivalent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule) program in, e.g., machine code, that, when executed, will behave in a way that is indistinguishable from the behavior of the program that your C++ source code described.

If you [take a look at the assembly](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BQKhUjRVhV1KZV1zQrOLHlfz7GqIBqWp4Dq%2BqGsaYimlGaxWpUNrSHaDpOhowDIMgGgTCMIR%2BvgRARtwwYaKG7zhkGXDRkqPDxgSiakMmqafABpCDLQOZ5gWRYlmWFZVjWFp1rBLaHO2ZwJj2MB9qO4bDq8A7EZ8yjIHoeg/MoLE/MMPzMk6oLgpClALi2S4rle6KYgQOJ4uSmDEmw%2B47nglLUrS9L7OeyDsuKqLchaLa/g%2BIpii%2BxDSpyH5sIq34CL%2B/6AdquogAA9FiXBCCakhQRaMH7LaSH%2BIICkaKpObDNhAZ4R09CEbJY5BiE5GRVRlyZsMtblAJNRtkIHZdnKvYQLc1VSS8kmfHgqEsfQ06zvOsLwkiq6mZulkHtZe7ivZjnHi5jJuR5q7eXegrCk%2BnndMFb5ym6EV8D%2BqrwLFwHxVIBpGqlEHpeapRtdl8H2o6zpjWhLEjKMtClbhkYhoNTxBos9U3ZRnYJs1ux8d9cFHF1InUZ9UhcOjgmdT1NF0nOj0gIsQA%3D) that's generated, you'll see that, in the case of plain integers being swapped, no sane compiler will move this temporary variable to memory but use registers to swap the values. You can trust your compiler to know what is the most efficient way to swap two integers on the given target architecture. If you can't trust your compiler to know that, then you should be looking for a better compiler…

Actually, it's hard to really say much about how "efficient" this `swap` function is just by looking at the code it generates in isolation. In practice, a function such as the `swap` above should normally be optimized away completely. The only trace it will normally leave in machine code is the effect it has on dataflow ([example here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5BwAMAQTny8LBiswBqAG6o86DYIDuTAA4QVBbgDYNTUhovWNAIwCUSjgHY%2BCjX4csBBoEALYmGhwAzAAitlE%2B8v62ETEu8RG%2B/s4psaEm8R6e0R4KShYaAGYQzqioDBrI7qXeSknlTDkaACxcBZl%2B5dlRsVyRfYr9DhUaEI2tSf5GphB2Lu6RCfN%2BxJgEYixxG4XFClKujNIArFKkLNKyN6jSAML8/Aai4prckbQ3BPczucANYgLiyAB0tEiAA5PJdZODZDCYV0upELlIujcQnRZLJboDSE8pDdBCACQCpA9znBYEg0GE8AxMGQKLNUEyWcQUMw2AB9AjEEQsYGkCrMgis8nVInOFRMYgAT2kf1IjJCmECAHlVCrqTcsCFWMAWUT8DtkAQ8FpMOSDaRMAAPTDIERS1U3CyYBhEtTOYiKpXPDCSKRqoV4XHhs6ME0oN68Rh4ZzkyDnVAma2oFj2gC02siZM%2BEjo519UmuhIdJKdMKseasXQafOAMyFIuBrhmuEIJAio3oGhDXNZA9%2B3devH4/0BrnOCEwTCwPIgILoAE4IRvIrIrFwujCNxvLpdPJ4YZdMdjSLjaPjqw9idIyRTSFSaaQ6YgUJyTMzWXIShGX/bkQGAGEMQlBgpWIGVnDlBVlU9dVOU1HU9XNTBjTYM0HQtV1rVte0n2dV13TDNVvQrJ9/UDZUQywFDI2jP5y3jThpyTf00zXYkszwHN80LYsxFLWhyyuG47hraQ6wbJsNGAZBkA0GEIUiHt8CIYhxyHEdQLHH4uEnRMeFnA151IRdl1ZSh11oLcdz3A8jxPM8LyvCsbxkp8SVfSk5y/GAfxAgC2WAv9wpALRkBMEx%2BS0Rz%2BXBfknSbcVJWlSgEIdeUWCDFCNS1AhdQYfUnyNE08MqvBLSIu0iTIt0PRjchAh9P0U3o4NQ2Y4go09di2ATLiBB4%2BAMwEoSQAAem1LghBLSQJMxKtfMeOTFJCQRYu0RyIXBLS%2B10n59Ki7lx0iUyxosml13Ba9pKJfyhDfD9Y2/CAGQuwD2TCsC8BUxz6Gg2D4MQgrkLa4qMPKrCcNNMNavqm1GodZqKJQ6iuoDINGMo/4BtY2NW1GvhuJTXipuzXNpALIslrElbJMrZ7ZKkeTG2bIHVIOyFaGOnS9PsAzwvHLobop8z3znB6CW89m/JfN7Ass1muCVzbSVl9XSFtODBLuLogA%3D%3D%3D)), but there will never be an actual call instruction to invoke a separate piece of machine code to do the swapping. The *really* important thing to do when it comes to optimizing `swap` is to make sure that the compiler *can* actually optimize it away (which generally comes down to making sure that it's defintion is known wherever it is used).

Moral of the story: Focus not on describing how you think the machine code should work, but on expressing your intentions in a way that is readable to both you and the compiler, and, first and foremost, in a way that *correctly* describes the intended *behavior* based on the rules of the language, not the rules of the target hardware. Never rely on what you *think* a certain language construct maps to at the machine level. Rely on what the C++ language *says* about the behavior a certain language construct gives rise to. Modern C++ compilers are *very good* at translating complex C++ code into very lean and efficient machine code that does *precisely* what was expressed in C++. They do so, however, by aggressively exploiting the fact that the behavior that was expressed is also *the only* behavior that has to be respected. As a result, modern C++ compilers are *very bad* at generating machine code that does not what was written but merely thought at the moment of writing…

Answer (score 2):

Swap using references would look like this:

```
void swap(int& a, int& b) {
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

You only put the `&` when declaring that it’s a reference, but not when using it. References can be used like regular variables.

Because you’re working with ints, this swap is just as efficient as the swap with `std::move`. Move semantics only provide a benefit when you’re working with classes that own resources.

For example, a vector owns a pointer to an array, so moving a vector is much more efficient than copying a vector because when you copy a vector, you have to copy all the data in the vector’s internal array. If you move a vector, on the other hand, it doesn’t have to copy the internal array. It only has to copy the pointer to the array, and that’s much, much faster.